# Reclaim storage space of failed XCode download from App Store

Tags: macos, updates, xcode, mac-app-store

On Macbook 120gb, i had available storage of 23gb. I already have Xcode 10.3 installed and saw a notification for a new update. I installed the update and it started download and completed almost 99% and failed for some reason. 
While the update was in progress i noticed the available storage to be 8gb but after the update failed the available storage space was 14gb. 
How can i reclaim the 9gb of storage which is lost after the failed XCode update?

Comment: Where are you getting the storage figure from? The **only** reliable one is in Disk Utility, under the volume's 'thermometer' display, labelled "Free". No other source takes purgeable space into account - See "Available" lower down.

Comment: I got the available storage figure from the Storage tab in the "About this Mac" window. 
Apple logo > About this Mac > Storage

Comment: So, you need to check the one in Disk Utility to see the correct figure.

Comment: It is the same in Disk Utility too

Answer (score 0):

2 years late, but i think i've found the solution,

1. i had to empty the caches, to do that, i opened finder, clicked on the 'go' menu, held down the option/alt key, clicked Library, then opened the Cache folder, and deleted everything
2. By using Daisy disk, i found out that following folder took up a lot space:
   /MacintoshHD/private/var/folders/***crypticString***/C/com.apple.appstoreagent.
   My thought was, that the xcode update files may be stored inside this folder.
   after some research i stumbled across this thread on stackexchange: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176371/can-i-delete-files-or-folders-from-private-var-folders
   but i did not want to risk, having to install macos again and/or corrupting anything since this is my laptop i use for work.